# My expo detached app build is failing on visual studio app center

Tags: azure, react-native, expo, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I have recently detached expo and trying to build that detached app on Microsoft visual studio app center. But the build is failing on the server.

Link for logs:
https://files.fm/u/9arwcnyp

PS: `react-native run-android` is also failing. I am building the app locally by `./android/gradlewinstallDevMinSdkDevKernelDebug`

my app.json:`{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "expo": "^30.0.1",
    "expokit": "1.7.1",
    "mobile-center": "^0.11.2",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
    "yarn": "^1.10.1"
  }
}`

Comment: Is this the same as what you're seeing?
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/189